# I have a navbar i want that the button inside navbar should touch the bottom of navbar border

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, alignment, navbar

min-height:0 is not working for me

```
.navbar{
min-height :0 !important; 
}
```

My code is below ->

```
1
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl">
    <button class="navbar-brand navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Topic <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item mydropdown" data-dropdown-toggle="hover">
                <button class="not-active nav-link dropdown-toggle" routerLink="/Science" routerLinkActive="myactive">Science</button>
                <div class="mydropdown__wrap">
                    <span class="carat"></span>
                    <div class="mydropdown_inr">
                        <div class="mydropdown__menu">
                            <button class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/English" routerLinkActive="myactive">english</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/Hindi" routerLinkActive="myactive">NewHindi</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

*** Bootstrap 4 ***

my aim is to remove the space between the button and the border of the navbar

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding to your problem, because you `search` button have two `dropdown` open already you cannot place that button on the bottom.

Comment: thank you it is done !t was just  that i used .navbar and added it to global style sheet... my bad ! So I chnged the name to .myNavbar{ min-height:0 !important ,padding:0 important} it worked for me very well AND added myNavbar as class.

Comment: that's great, then!